# why I can not store selected value by $_POST in php

Tags: php, select, post

I create a dropdown list to select values:

```
 <form action="." method="post" id="aligned">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update_customer">
    <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" 
           value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($customer['customerID']); ?>"> 


    <label>Country:</label>
    <select name="selected">
     <?php  

        $dbhost = 'localhost';
        $dbuser = 'root';
        $dbpass ='';
        $db = 'tech_support';

        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
        if(!$conn)
            die('Could not connect: '. mysql_error());

        mysql_select_db($db);
        $selected= mysql_query("select * from countries where countryCode = '" .$customer['countryCode']. "'");
        $sql = mysql_query("select * from countries order by countryName");

        if($selectedrow = mysql_fetch_array($selected)){
             echo "<option selected value=\"VALUE\">" . $selectedrow['countryName']."</option>";
        }
         //echo "<select>";

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo "<option value =\"VALUE\">". $row['countryName']."</option>";
        }
        //echo "</select>";
       ?> 
    </select><br>
```

In another php file as below, I was trying to store the selected value for Country, but nothing is stored, why?

```
<?php $country_name = $_POST["selected"];
echo $country_name;//it always print out 'VALUE'-I guess it means null.
?>
```

Comment: `echo "<option value =\"VALUE\">"` because you set the actual value to `VALUE`

Comment: replace VALUE with any parameter or variable... `echo "<option selected value="'.$selectedrow['countryName'].'">" . $selectedrow['countryName']."</option>";
        }`

Comment: try this echo "<option value ='".$row['countryName']."'>". $row['countryName']."</option>";

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated since PHP 5.5 (and **removed entirely** in PHP 7) and you should [stop using them](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942) if you can. 
You should choose another API that allows you to use [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/) (which you *really should* when dealing with variables), like `mysqli_*` or PDO 
- see [choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
echo "<option value ='".$row['countryName']."'>". $row['countryName']."</option>";
```

And I want to add something, MySQL is deprecated in PHP5 and removed from PHP7. what is your PHP version. If you use PHP 5 or later use mysqli.

Comment: WELL, when I connect to localhost using mysqli, it works fine. But once connected to remote server mysqli doesn't work for queries somehow. I am using mysql php5.

Comment: Check your connection of mysqli on remote server. If it us fine then, you are wrong in sending query to server. What is PHP version of your remote server.

Comment: I am using PHP 5.6. Mysqli connected to server since no error printed out. But the query result was not correctly presented.